# Question for SAP DBTech JDBC when trigger is execute

Tags: sapui5

I would like to ask what is this error and how do I fix for it?

**SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: trigger execution with transition variable is not supported with piecewise lob writing.**

Situation:

Read from a file that more than 100kb. Then insert into SAP HANA database.
The column to be inserted is BLOB type.
This table have a trigger which will insert the same information into another table (For tracking purpose).

If without this trigger, it able to insert data without any error.

I cannot give the actual code due to confidential. So I create a sample below.

I'm create a hdbtrigger file and compile it using SAP HANA Database Module in SAP Web IDE to create the table, trigger, etc.

```
TRIGGER "M_IMG_T_T" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON "M_IMG_T"
REFERENCING NEW ROW new_row, OLD ROW old_row
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE upd_kbn VARCHAR(1) := 'U';
    IF :new_row."ID_PK" IS NULL THEN
        upd_kbn = 'D';
    ELSEIF :old_row."ID_PK" IS NULL THEN
        upd_kbn = 'I';
    END IF;

    IF :upd_kbn = 'I' OR :upd_kbn = 'U' THEN
        INSERT INTO "M_IMG_T_H" VALUES(
            :new_row."ID_PK",
            :new_row."I_IMG_FILE_DATA"
        );
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO "M_IMG_T_H" VALUES(
            :new_row."ID_PK",
            :new_row."I_IMG_FILE_DATA"
        );
    END IF;
END
```

When I export catalog of the table, I will get this. (I just copy insert part)

```
CREATE TRIGGER "M_IMG_T_T_I" AFTER INSERT ON "M_IMG_T" REFERENCING NEW ROW NEW_ROW FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE UPD_CLS VARCHAR(2) := 'I';
    INSERT INTO "M_IMG_T_H" (
        "I_ID",
        "I_IMG_FILE_DATA"
    ) VALUES(
        :NEW_ROW."I_ID",
        :NEW_ROW."I_IMG_FILE_DATA"
    );
END
```

Comment: From your description, it would appear that a trigger is causing a problem. Can you [edit] your question and post the trigger code?

Comment: @Abra I've added the trigger code. Please have a look. Thank you ^^

Comment: `DECLARE` must precede `BEGIN`.